# Add more results in google map dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on this from several hours but no success.
This code is working fine one time and add 100 records on map. Then I want to add more results from db after first 100. how can I do that please guide me. Here is the code.
I also try with ajax but json damage after result came back from php so that is also not work for me.

```
<div class="span12 geoData">

    <?php

    $db = new db();
    $data = array();
    $tweets = array();
    $counter = 0;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tweets` WHERE `geo_lat` != 0 LIMIT 100";
    $results = $db->select($query);

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($results);

    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) !=FALSE) {
        $tweets[$counter]['tweet_text'] =  $row['tweet_text'];
        $tweets[$counter]['geo_lat'] =  $row['geo_lat'];
        $tweets[$counter]['geo_long'] =  $row['geo_long'];

        $counter++;
    }

    $data['count'] = $count;
    $data['tweets'] = $tweets;


    $jsonData = json_encode($data);

    ?>
    <script src="mapsApi.js"></script>
    <script src="markerclusterer_compiled.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    var data = <?php echo $jsonData; ?>;

    function initialize() {       

    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(39.744408452010475, -100.15602825000002);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "holding..."
    });

    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
    var contentSTR = '<div id="info"><p><span>Ttitle:</span> '+ data.tweets[i].tweet_text + '</p></div>';
    var dataTweets = data.tweets[i];
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataTweets.geo_lat,
                                      dataTweets.geo_long);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        html: contentSTR,           
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
        infowindow.open(map, this);

    });

    markers.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers); 
}                         
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>

<div id="map-container">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>              


</div>
```

Comment: data that return from ajax response is not completed json. I think when " or ' come it break the json

Comment: you'll propbably need to escape " and ' in that case.  It would be helpful to show us both the javascript code you're using for calling the AJAX, and the PHP code you're then using to return the JSON data